# Calculate burden resistor value of current transformer and measure ac current with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, electricity

I Want to measure AC current with current transformer but i dont know exact value of burden resistor or calculation formula...i want to measure current of borewell pump. company specified pump as 1.5Hp power.

[image: current transformer]

Answer (score 4):

There is no "You need X resistor for Y transformer". The resistor you choose depends on what current range you are working with and what voltage range you want that to be expressed as.

That transformer is a 100:5 (or more properly a 20:1) ratio.  That means for every 20A going through it you get 1A out.

That output current is then passed through a burden resistor and you measure the voltage across that resistor.

If you are, for example, working with sensing up to 1A current then the maximum current you'd get out of it would be 1/20A, or 50mA.  If you want that to be expressed reliably within the range of a 5V ADC then you would:

1. Work from the mid-range of the ADC as 0V to give ±2.5V (assuming AC)
2. Calculate the resistor that gives 2.5V across it when 50mA is passed through it
3. Pick the next-lowest common resistor value.
4. Reverse the calculation to get the voltage range you now have.

In this example, R=V/I, so 2.5/0.05 = 50Ω.  50Ω resistors aren't common, but 47Ω ones are, so you'd pick that.

Then reversing it gives V=IR = 0.05 * 47 = ±2.35V

Give it a 2.5V offset to the ADC and you can now read points on a sinewave between 0.15V and 4.85V at 1A sensed current.

Comment: Thanks for answer..I want to measure about 5 to 6 amps of current with this transformer. Then what value of resistor is required for this??

Comment: Have you tried doing the maths?

Comment: What if you want to measure the whole 5 amps. With the 5v from Arduino its giving me 1 ohm. Is there a power rating I need to worry about in the burden resistor?